# how to hide variable on url over coldfusion

Tags: html, coldfusion-9

I would like to hide the variable "?product=#getproduct#" as soon as the new tab get open in the browser

```html
<td><a href="##" onClick="window.open('http://p-test/testcase.cfm?product=<cfoutput>#getproduct#</cfoutput>', '_blank','width=720,height=880,  toolbar=no,location=no,directories=no,statu s=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,copyhistory=no,resizable=no')">info</a></td>
```

Any ideas, how to hide the variable, as soon the new tab is open...so that it only dispaly http://p-test/testcase.cfm in the address bar, but the content doesn't change? thx

Answer (score 1):

Why are you even trying to hide it? `GET` query string params should be considered public data. You're going to jump thru more hoops to try and hide them. I'm not even sure you can remove a param in Javascript after the page has loaded.

If you're trying to hide the value you're better off using two-way encryption/decryption (but make sure the values are URL-safe) and just obfuscating the values.

You could look into the Coldfusion `encrypt` and `decrypt` functions:

https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-e-g/encrypt.html